# Inserting a .gz into Google Drive with the SDK causes it to download with a .path extension

Tags: google-drive-api

When I use the Google Drive SDK to insert a .gz file into My Drive and then go to the UI to download it the file has a '.path' extension appended to its filename. If I download a .gz file that I've uploaded through the UI I don't run into that issue. Anyone familiar with what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behaviour with Google Drive SDK and uploading a zip file. If you try and download the file, it gets ".path" appended to the filename.

If I look at the metadata for the file, I can see that the originalFilename field is set to "local.path" but attempting to update this value results in no change.